# iOS MapKit does not load tiles on maximum zoom on MKMapTypeHybrid

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mapkit, mkmapview

I am facing a problem in my region because MapKit does not download the last set of tiles (most likely because it does not exist) but the problem is that instead of just show the previous tiles, it actually removes! the tiles and shows nothing.

The image bellow illustrates just before I reach maximum zoom:

[image]

And the image bellow show how tiles are displayed when I reach maximum zoom:

[image]

Can someone tell if there is a way of stopping iOS MapKit to try to download tiles at a zoom that there is no imagery for it? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like it also affects the satellite view. The only map I'm not seeing this issue on is the road/street view.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way of stopping this. In fact, there's not even a way to detect this scenario because it depends on satellite imagery availability. I've logged a [radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/12159465) back in 2012 for this. You might wanna dupe it to raise awareness.